# Pandas - nested json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new in Python, would like to extract data from json with Padas.

Json nested structure is as follows:

```
{
    "idDriver": "100001",
    "defaultTripType": "private",
    "fleetManagerRole": null,
    "identifications": [
        {
            "code": "90-00-00-77-20",
            "from": "2019-08-08T10:38:15Z",
            "rawId": "",
            "vehicle": {
                "isBusinessCar": "0",
                "id": "10000",
                "licensePlate": "ABCD",
                "class": "Suziki 1.6 CDTI",
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As an output I would need on one line: 'idDriver' from level 0 and then ‘licensePlate’ from identifications/ vehicle node in one line:

What I have been tried to apply is:

(after loading data from API what works fine)

```
json_data = json.loads(myResponse.text)

#only unwrapping 'identifications' – works 100% fine
workdata = json_normalize(json_data, record_path= ['identifications'], 
                     meta=['idDriver'])

#unwrapping 'identifications'\'vehicle'  - is NOT working
workdata = json_normalize(json_data, record_path= ['identifications','vehicle'], 
                     meta=['idDriver'])
```

I would appreciate any hint on that.

Kind Regards,
Arek

Comment: json_normalize - “Normalize” semi-structured JSON data into a flat table : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html, Are you looking for single value or entire row?

Comment: I am looing as an output for entire table with columns: idDriver and licensePlate.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for rebuilding your dictionary like this:

```
New_Data = {
"id" : [],
"licensePlate" : []
}

New_Data["id"].append(data["idDriver"])
New_Data["licensePlate"].append(data["identifications"][0]["vehicle"]["licensePlate"])
```

If you have many data["identifications"] you can easly look over them, if you have many drivers you can do it as well.

Comment: Thnaks DavidE, biut how your 'data' should look like in New_Data["id"].append(data["idDriver"])?

Comment: data is your json data, you store your json data in a variable right? i just called this variable data.

Answer (score 0):

For me your first code working nice, only if necessary remove `vehicle.` text from columns names:

```
json_data  = {
    "idDriver": "100001",
    "defaultTripType": "private",
    "fleetManagerRole": 'null',
    "identifications": [
        {
            "code": "90-00-00-77-20",
            "from": "2019-08-08T10:38:15Z",
            "rawId": "",
            "vehicle": {
                "isBusinessCar": "0",
                "id": "10000",
                "licensePlate": "ABCD",
                "class": "Suziki 1.6 CDTI",
                }
            }
    ]
}
workdata = json_normalize(json_data, record_path= ['identifications'],  meta=['idDriver'])
print (workdata)
             code                  from rawId vehicle.isBusinessCar  \
0  90-00-00-77-20  2019-08-08T10:38:15Z                           0   

  vehicle.id vehicle.licensePlate    vehicle.class idDriver  
0      10000                 ABCD  Suziki 1.6 CDTI   100001  

workdata.columns = workdata.columns.str.replace('vehicle\.','')
print (workdata)
             code                  from rawId isBusinessCar     id  \
0  90-00-00-77-20  2019-08-08T10:38:15Z                   0  10000   

  licensePlate            class idDriver  
0         ABCD  Suziki 1.6 CDTI   100001
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a package to deal with tasks like this easily, it's called [cherrypicker](https://cherrypicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I think the following snippet would achieve your task with CherryPicker:

```
from cherrypicker import CherryPicker

json_data = json.loads(myResponse.text)
picker = CherryPicker(json_data)

flat_data = picker.flatten['idDriver', 'identifications_0_vehicle_licensePlate'].get()
```

`flat_data` would then look like this (I'm assuming that your data is actually a list of objects like the one you described above):

```
[['100001', 'ABCD'], ...]
```

You can then load this into a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(flat_data, columns=["idDriver", "licensePlate"])
```

If you want to flatten your data in slightly different ways (e.g. you want every license plate/driver ID combination, not just the first license plate for each driver), then you should be able to do this too although it may require two or three lines rather than just one. Check our the docs for examples of other ways of using it: https://cherrypicker.readthedocs.io.

To install cherrypicker, it's just `pip install --user cherrypicker`.